# DIV, SPAN elements half visible

Tags: css, sharethis

I'm using a wordpress theme which is all good but when I add sharethis buttons, they are half visible. I've tried everything but couldn't locate the exact issue.

Look at top of the page.

site URL: http://ccl5.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.stButton .stButton_gradient {height: 16px}
```

This css cause the elements to take only half of its height. That css is generated by sharethis itself.

You can add this css to override.

```
.stButton .stButton_gradient, .stButton .stFb, .stButton .stTwbutton, .stButton .stMainServices {height: 22px !important}
```

Thanks

Comment: I've added ur code to my css file. Now only G+ button is full visible, not all buttons.
And I tried other DIVs in my posts and surprisingly they were half visible too. So I need something global declaration in my css but unable to locate exact class causing issue

Comment: i have edited the css, hope you took the full line, right ? initially i just added code for google plus only. Now its for all the elements..

Comment: yeah initially i just forgot to include full line :) now you got the full css right ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix 
update heights for the containers as follows:

```
    .stButton .stButton_gradient
    {
        height:26px;
    }

    .stButton .stFb, .stButton .stTwbutton, .stButton .stMainServices
    {

        height:26px;
    }
```

this fix will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please specify a ShareThis Publisher Key *(For help, contact support@sharethis.com)* on your site.

Secondly, to answer your question, the file buttons.css contains the following code *(at line 139)*:

```
.stButton .stButton_gradient {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    padding: 2px;
    font-family: serif;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    height:  21px;
    background: #d5d5d5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d5d5d5 0, #efefef 48%, #fff 94%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #d5d5d5), color-stop(48%, #efefef), color-stop(94%, #fff));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#d5d5d5', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
}
```

Firstly remove the line:

```
height:  21px;
```

as it is causing you problems.

Thirdly please remove the line:

```
height: 16px;
```

from this passage *(line 737)*:

```
.stButton .stFb, .stButton .stTwbutton, .stButton .stMainServices {
    background-image: url(/images/facebook_counter.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 16px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    line-height: 16px;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

as this is also causing problems.

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: I think I do not have access to buttons.css